# OpenJPA Mysql always getting id null

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, openjpa

I'm trying to run a simple example which is just a mapping with a table and to print all the values stored in it. 
I'm getting all my fields well except my id.

Here is my table when i do an export on it

```sql
CREATE TABLE `adress` ( 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`streetNumber` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
`street` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
`city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
`zipCode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`state` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

LOCK TABLES `adress` WRITE; 
INSERT INTO `adress` VALUES (1,12,'Canada street','LOS ANGELES',441233,'California'),(2,54,'5th avenue','NEW YORK CITY',884769,'New York'); 
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

My Entity class :

```java
@Entity 
@Table(name = "adress") 
@XmlRootElement 
public class Adress implements Serializable { 

   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
   @Basic(optional = false) 
   @Column(name = "id") 
   private Integer id; 

   @Column(name = "streetNumber") 
   private Short streetNumber; 

...
```

If i do a "findAll()" i'm able to get all my datas from the db. 
But the id is null, all the other fields have their values

I have tried several stuff but i'm not going everywhere.

If someone can see where or about what is my mistake i'll appreciate a lot your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, can you clarify these things :
1) In database also value of `id` field is null ?
2) In database value of `id` field is properly gone but its not coming while reading from database ?